# Firestore - after adding .whereEqualTo data doesn't refresh in real time

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

After adding the method .whereEqualsThis data doesn't refresh in real time. I need to switch to a different screen and come back to get a refresh. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Here's the code:

```
        Query query = dailyGoalsRef.whereEqualTo("isNotToDisplay", false).orderBy("date", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<DailyGoalsModel> firestoreRecyclerOptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<DailyGoalsModel>()
            .setQuery(query, DailyGoalsModel.class)
            .build();

    firestoreRecyclerAdapter =
            new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<DailyGoalsModel, DailyGoalsHolder>(firestoreRecyclerOptions) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DailyGoalsHolder holder, int position, @NonNull DailyGoalsModel model) {
                    String fragmentName = "dailyGoals";
                    holder.setGoalsList(context, userEmail, model, fragmentName);
                }

                @NonNull
                @Override
                public DailyGoalsHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.daily_goals_list, parent, false);
                    return new DailyGoalsHolder(view);
                }

                @Override
                public void onDataChanged() {
                    if (progressBar != null) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    if (getItemCount() == 0) {
                        recyclerView.setVisibility((View.GONE));
                        emptyView.setVisibility((View.VISIBLE));
                    } else {
                        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public int getItemCount() {
                    return super.getItemCount();
                }
            };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(firestoreRecyclerAdapter);
    return layout;
```

Firestore:
[image]

change in value "isNotToDispaly"

```
if ((date.getTime()) < (todayDate.getTime() - 2*24*60*60*1000)) {
            rootRef.collection("goalsData").document(userEmail).collection(fragmentName).document(goalsId).update("isNotToDisplay", true);
        }
```

it is located in

```
public void setGoalsList(final Context context, String userEmail, DailyGoalsModel goalsModel, String fragmentName)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I need to switch to a different screen and come back to get a refresh".  Adding a filter like this shouldn't stop realtime updates to documents matched by the query.

Comment: I thought so too. There is nothing strange in the submitted code?

Comment: Not enough information to say here.  You haven't shown what documents your query finds, and what changes to those documents or results that should cause a change.  Right now you're just kinda saying "it doesn't work" without giving your observations.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to bring my problem to light. Adding the ".whereEqualTo" method literally corrupts the refresh in real time. When it is not there, everything works correctly. I checked how the program behaves in the case of another field in the 'where' condition - it does not change anything. I also tried to combine with removing progressBar, because in the absence of data to display, instead of the arrival of the EmptyView control, progressBar is still active (maybe this is some hint?). Additionally, I edited the post to provide more information.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem. It was unusual, because it was about not adding an index in the Firebase platform.